is NextJs compatible with docker compose watch?
I'm trying to use docker compose up --watch with NextJs and node. The hot reloading and even f5 is not working. Nothing is updated when I modify page.tsx for exemple.
The Dockerfile :
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN npm install

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm","run","start"]

docker-compose.yml :
services:
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    # volumes:
    #   - ./frontend:/app
    develop:
      watch:
        - action: sync+restart
          path: ./app
          target: /src/app
          ignore:
            - node_modules/
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    # env_file:
    #   - ./.env.local
  
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    # volumes:
    #   - ./backend:/app
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    develop:
       watch:
         - action: sync
           path: ./app
           target: /src/app

The project :
myproject
|--frontend
|----.next
|----src/app/page.tsx
|----Dockerfile
|--backend
|--docker-compose.yml

